# npm package.json defined bin module - command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I'm getting `command not found...` on a **bin** module I defined in my package.json.  **Why?**  I thought it was supposed to automatically map a local command into path.

In my module's package.json:

```
  "bin": {
    "testme": "./misc/testme"
  },
```

./misc/testme script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log("this is a test");
```

It appears in the node_modules/.bin directory

```
$ ls node_modules/.bin
acorn       escodegen    gulp        kue-dashboard  ncp                 semver               stylus
cake        esgenerate   gzip-size   lessc          nopt                shjs                 testme
cleancss    esparse      handlebars  make-plural    pretty-bytes        sshpk-conv           uglifyjs
coffee      esvalidate   image-size  messageformat  rc                  sshpk-sign           user-home
dateformat  express      jade        mime           retrieve-arguments  sshpk-verify         uuid
dot-object  geojsonhint  jsonlint    mkdirp         rimraf              strip-indent         watchr
errno       grunt        js-yaml     mustache       sails               strip-json-comments  which
```

But, after `npm install` when I run it, I get:

```
$ testme
bash: testme: command not found...
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe that running `testme` would only be possible if you'd install the package globally. In order to run this command (without the global installation) you'd have to `npm run testme` and add this to your package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "testme": "./bin/testme"
```

more info here: http://2ality.com/2016/01/locally-installed-npm-executables.html

Answer (score 6):

For me, on Windows, had to run

> npm link

in the root folder of my project before the commands begins executing. I don't know if it applies to other OS

Comment: It also worked on Linux Mint. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways (that I can think of to run this command) :-

a(as told by @TAMAS) .

```
 npm install -g testme
```

b.

```
 PATH = $PATH:/your/project/dir/node_modules/.bin
    
 EXPORT PATH
```